# SImon Says Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I want to make a simon says game with a functionality [like this](http://www.kellyking.me/projects/simon/).

I have the following code :

HTML

```
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="yellow"></div>

<div id="count"></div>
<div id="buttons">
   <button id="1" type="button" class="btn btn-default"onclick="add_sequence()">Simple </button>
   <button id="2" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Strict </button>
   <button id="3" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Restart</button>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var sequence = ["#red", "#blue", "#yellow", "#green","#red"];  //etc.
var human = []; 
var i = 0;

function add_sequence() {
   human.push(sequence[i])
   animate(human);

   $("" + human[i] + "").click(function() {
      human.push(sequence[i])
      animate(human);
      i++;     
   }

   function animate(s) {
      var i = 0;
      var interval = setInterval(function() {

      anim(s[i]);
      i++;
      if (i >= s[i].length) {
         clearInterval(interval);
      }
   }, 500);
}

function anim(id) {

  $("" + id + "").delay(500)
     .animate({
       opacity: 1
     }, 300)
     .animate({
       opacity: 0.5
     }, 300)
}
```

My way of thinking is that every time I click on a button or series of buttons, (etc...), to add one element to the human array from the sequence array. In this way the next round will have an addition of one more lighting button.

BUT I can't do this with this code because the increment of the lighting buttons is done only when I click the first button(#red), not when I click the correct sequence of buttons.

Comment: That project is open source. Why not get the code and figure it out?

Comment: Because for specific reasons I want to make the above code with the specific logic to work and to know why is not working.

Comment: No.  Why capture IDs?  All you need is an enum/array.  Every time a click is made you shift the array index and compare to the clicked element.

Comment: Can you give me an example?